# Inserting records into sqlite database only when the database is first created

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I want to insert records into my sqlite database only when the database is created (i.e. only when my app installs for the first time on a device).
I googled for help and some people suggested to insert the data in the 
`onCreate()` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, but records couldn't be inserted using that method.

This is my code

```
public class EventsData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "events.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Table name
    public static final String TABLE = "events";

    // Columns
    public static final String NAME = "first";
    public static final String TITLE = "second";

    public EventsData(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE+"(" + _ID + "INTEGER PRMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME +"TEXT, " + TITLE + "TEXT NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE +" VALUES (1,'david','packard')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
                    onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple solution is to use prepopulated database,HOW? check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Comment: no... i could add records from the main activity, but couldnt do the same from "SQLiteOpenHelper" class

Answer (score 1):

use sqlite database browser to make datbase it will help a lot
try this link [Inserting data to record in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108268/inserting-data-to-record-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Looks in you CREATE TABLE query spaces are missing between texts....

```
NAME +"TEXT, " + TITLE + "TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

Just print the queries in SOP and try to execute them in you SQLITe tools on desktop.

Comment: no... i could add records from the main activity, but couldnt do the same from "SQLiteOpenHelper" class :-(  even after correcting the errors

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine when you get the `CREATE` statement right.  It's missing spaces and correct spellings.  `_ID + "INTEGER`... must be _ID + " INTEGER`and`PRMARY`must be`PRIMARY`.  There may be other mistakes. It's a good idea to have a debugging option in your program to emit all SQL you're executing to the log.