# Inserting data to record in sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-date

I have to make an Android application in which i have to store predefined question and answer, using sqlite to store data. I found tutorials in which values are inserted every time we run the application, but i have to insert these questions and answers in the program to make my database.
Can someone suggest me any tutorial wich explain how to insert the values in table?

Comment: if i could not make my self clear then please ask your confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all download sqlite browser and open your .db file which ideally should be in your assets folder, and insert all the records in respective table either manually or by query.

Then save that db file and copy that file in the assets folder of your project.

Then create databasehelper class and make it extend SQLiteOpenHelper and define your database and all the functions to fetch data over there.

Let me know if you have further doubts :)

[download sqlite browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.tutionimage/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "master_subject.db";
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private final Context myContext;
private boolean add2;

/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    // Toast.makeText(myContext, "Copy Done", 300).show();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDatabase != null)
        myDatabase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the
    // database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDatabase.query(....)" so
    // it'd be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.
}

//Insert Title into database
public long insertTitle(String sem, String subject,String jee, String chp, String marks, String time) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put("sem", sem);
    initialValues.put("subject", subject);
    initialValues.put("jee_flag", jee);
    initialValues.put("chapter", chp);
    initialValues.put("marks", marks);
    initialValues.put("time", time);

    return myDatabase.insert("testdata", null, initialValues);
}

//Fetching data from the database
public Cursor getTestData() throws SQLException{

    Cursor cursor = null;
    String queryString = "";


        if(NewStartPanel.queryString.split("-")[2].equalsIgnoreCase("n")){

            queryString = "select * from testdata where jee_flag='n' order by id desc";

        }

        else if(NewStartPanel.queryString.split("-")[2].equalsIgnoreCase("y")){

            queryString = "select * from testdata where jee_flag='y' order by id desc";
        }

        System.out.println("Query String:................  "+queryString);
        cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery(queryString, null);

    //  cursor.moveToFirst();

        System.out.println("cursor count of testdata is:"+cursor.getCount());


    return cursor;

}
```

TestOrReport.java

```
    public class TestOrReport extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test_or_report);

    // set resources

    //Interacting with database

    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper =new DataBaseHelper(this);
    System.out.println("Before open db");
    dataBaseHelper.openDataBase();

    System.out.println("After open db");
    Cursor mCursor = dataBaseHelper.getTestData();

    System.out.println("@@ total rows :"+mCursor.getCount());


    // Then you can iterate through cursor and get those data in arraylist or whatever collection you want to
    }

    }
```

Comment: I make the data base but i don't know how to use it with my android application suggest me some tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to preload questions and answers into a `sqlite` database. The following tutorial will help you with preloading a `sqlite` database...

[**Using your own SQLite database in Android applications**](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Also you will find many projects in [**github**](https://github.com/) for the same. One is [Android Survey App](https://github.com/tarun29061990/Android_Survey_App).

Hope this helps.