# Attempt to reopen an already-closed object sqlitedatabase while initializing database, android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I know there are lot of duplicate questions asked but I haven't found my answer yet.

Here is my code:
I have DatabaseHandler class where I have two methods `createTestTable(db);`
and `initializeTestTable(db);`

```
        public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AttendanceManagement";

        private static DatabaseHandler sInstance;

        public static synchronized DatabaseHandler getInstance(Context context) {

            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = new DatabaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return sInstance;
        }

        private DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        // Creating Tables
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            createTestTable(db);
            initializeTestTable(db);
        }

        private void createTestTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_TEST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test" + "("
                    + "name TEXT" + ")";

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TEST_TABLE);
        }

        private void initializeTestTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {

//      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//      when I execute above code line I get following error.
//      java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("name", "test1");

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert("test", null, values);
            db.close();

        }

    }
```

Inside my activity I have following code in `onCreate()`

```
db = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(this);
db.getWritableDatabase();
```

My application crashes after second line  `db.getWritableDatabase();`

I am getting following crash log

```
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cms.attendance/com.cms.attendance.fingerprintreader.newui.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.cms.attendance/databases/AttendanceManagement
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.cms.attendance/databases/AttendanceManagement
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:520)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:263)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at com.cms.attendance.fingerprintreader.newui.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:96)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-03 10:46:33.130: E/AndroidRuntime(5727):     ... 11 more
```

Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

Comment: youre db is probably close. try to open it first

Comment: db is not closed, it is open

Comment: in you're method, initializeTestTable you close it after insert. then you call the getWritableDatabase when its close.

Comment: I commented that line and I am still getting the same error

Comment: you should open you're db first, check the code here. also you can use the database helper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108268/inserting-data-to-record-in-sqlite

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try to implement that answer

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            createTestTable(db);
            initializeTestTable(getInstance(context));
        }
```

As you need to reinitialize the db and then you can close it.

Comment: getInstance(context) gives me object of DatabaseHandler and I need SqliteDatabase object

Answer (score 0):

- Take a look at this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/
- Make sure that after any modification you increment the version of the database so that the database gets recreated.
- However in the onCreate method, you shouldn't close the db, as this is not done in the best practices to implement the helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your database in application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private DatabaseHandler dbAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        dbAdapter = new DatabaseHandler (getApplicationContext());
        dbAdapter.open();
    }
```

and in class you can get by following code

```
MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) this.getApplication();
DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter= myApplication.getDatabaseAdapter();
```